# How to import angular.IInjectorService using the ES6 module syntax in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

How do I import the angular.IInjectorService from the [angular.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts) file using the ES6 module syntax in [TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript)?

**EDIT:** What I'd really like to know is how I can use the `IInjectorService` without fully qualifying it. In other words, I want to do this:

```
class TestCtrl {
    constructor($injector: IInjectorService) {...}
}
```

Instead of this:

```
class TestCtrl {
    constructor($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService) {...}
}
```

Currently, I'm doing it the internal module way. Something like this:

```
///<reference path="../path/to/typeDefinitions/angularjs/angular" />

import IInjectorService = ng.auto.IInjectorService;

class TestCtrl {
    constructor($injector: IInjectorService) {...}
}
```

My question is, is there an ES6 way to accomplish this? For example, something like the following pseudocode:

```
import {IInjectorService} from '../path/to/typeDefinitions/angularjs/angular';

class TestCtrl {
    constructor($injector: IInjectorService) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work:

```
import {auto as ngAuto} from "angular";
var foo:ngAuto.IInjectorService;
```

However I'd like to say that `auto` was a poor decision (but then again so was the `I` prefix). TypeScript was new when angular definitions were written and due to the popularity of angular we haven't had the opportunity to refactor it into a better one.

Comment: Note to myself and other developers: Make sure to include the reference `/// <reference path="../path/to/angular" />`. It doesn't work without it.

Comment: It does if your IDE supports tsconfig.json : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

Answer (score 2):

It is under the `auto` module and it will be typed as `IInjectorService`

You can use it like this:

```
class TestCtrl {
  myReference: any;
  constructor($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService){
    myReference = $injector.get('name');
  }
}
```